# How to get the shortest path in a weighted graph with NetworkX?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, shortest-path

I'm trying to get the shortest path in a weighted graph defined as

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge(131,673,weight=673)
g.add_edge(131,201,weight=201)
g.add_edge(673,96,weight=96)
g.add_edge(201,96,weight=96)
nx.draw(g,with_labels=True,with_weight=True)
plt.show()
```

to do so I use

```
nx.shortest_path(g,source=131,target=96)
```

The expected answer is 131,201,96 because for that path I have the least sum of weights. I'm getting 131,673,96 instead. I tried changing the weights but `shortest_path` always returns the *longest* path apparently. What is going on?

Comment: 131, 673, 96 its exactly the shortest paths. unless you have changing your weights

Comment: @Camue but the sum of 131,673,96 is more than 131,201,96 so how can it be the shortest path? is there something i need to know about how weights works.. the more the weight between two nodes the farther apart they are right?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

from the [documentation of nx.shortest_path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path):

> ```
> shortest_path(G, source=None, target=None, weight=None, method='dijkstra')[source]
> Compute shortest paths in the graph.
>
> Parameters
> G (NetworkX graph)
>
> source (node, optional) – Starting node for path. If not specified, compute shortest paths for each possible starting node.
>
> target (node, optional) – Ending node for path. If not specified, compute shortest paths to all possible nodes.
> ```
>
> *>     weight* 
>   (None or string, optional (default = None)) – If None, every edge has weight/distance/cost 1. If a string, use this edge
>       attribute as the edge weight. Any edge attribute not present defaults
>       to 1.
>
> ```
> method (string, optional (default = ‘dijkstra’)) – The algorithm to use to compute the path. Supported options: ‘dijkstra’,
> ```

(emphasis mine)

If you do not explictly state that you want to find the shortest weighted path (by specifying the `weight`argument), all weights are taken to be one.

To fix your problem, do:

```
print(nx.shortest_path(g,source=131,target=96, weight='weight'))
```

output:

```
[131, 201, 96]
```

Comment: The "weight='weight'" did the trick for me. Thank you for sharing your solution